# Can install packages but can't import in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have installed django multiselectfield using the command

```
pip install django-multiselectfield
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-multiselectfield in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\sit
e-packages (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=1.4 in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\d
jango-2.0.3-py3.7.egg (from django-multiselectfield) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pytz-201
9.1-py3.7.egg (from django>=1.4->django-multiselectfield) (2019.1)
```

I am unable to import the package multiselectfield in my program.

python version: 3.7.3

pip version: 19.1.1

Comment: Have you added it into installed apps?

Comment: can you show how you are trying to import it?

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Yes. I did

Comment: @Exprator I used 'from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField' in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed python2 package using `pip install django-multiselectfield`

Install it using `pip3 install django-multiselectfield` since you are using python 3.7.3

if you don't have pip3 ,

use `apt-get install python3-pip`

if you are using a virtual environment then you have to install in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using venv (virtual environment) there installed packages is not associate to your project , please verify that you are working with base python 3.7 as pip installed it packages to .

Answer (score 0):

Have you already add this app to your settings.py ?
and make sure installed use right pip.

Comment: Yes i added 'multiselectfield' in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. Could you tell me about the pip more specifically?

Comment: Make sure use right pip  like  pip3.7 , more time we use pip install app to default python,not your aurrent python version.